# Ubuntu as Gateway - Client PC no internet

Tags: networking, server, internet, gateway

**Ubuntu configurations**

**Ifconfig**

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:0e:15:94  
          inet addr:192.168.1.129  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2d58:5175:4354:3a62/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:120b:2c4f:1e60:9573:9a86:d356:ad94/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:120b:2c4f:1e60:4098:7cf5:6187:401a/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13451 (13.4 KB)  TX bytes:16919 (16.9 KB)

ens34     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:0e:15:9e  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe0e:159e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:5691 (5.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:17506 (17.5 KB)  TX bytes:17506 (17.5 KB)
```

**Interfaces ubuntu**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto ens34

    iface ens34 inet static
      address 10.0.0.1
      netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**Port forwarding**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**Routes**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens34
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens34
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
```

**Iptables**

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Client PC configurations - Windows 10 - Lan nic**

```
IP: 10.0.0.2
MASK: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.1

Dns Server: 10.0.0.1
```

On the ubuntu server i'm able to access the internet, but from the client pc (windows) using the configurations above it's not possible to reach the internet.

Ping 10.0.0.1 gateway from client windows pc works..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IPTABLES` to do the trick.
You need to forward the traffic from one interface (your 10.0.0.1 interface to the 192.168.129 interface).

Run the following rules:

```
#/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
#/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens34 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i ens34 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Do i need to bridge the connection between ens33 and ens34?

Comment: After applying the rules above ...still without internet ... (Updated post with data from iptables)

Comment: Sorry.. I think I made a mistake with the rule regarding the interface order (it's hard to do it by head). Can you delete all the rules for iptables with `iptables -F` (make sure you don't have other rules, if not it will delete them all. And apply the updated rules.