# Unable to use Ubuntu 17.4 as internet gateway

Tags: lan, gateway

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 virtual machine to act as a router/gateway for other VMs I have on an isolated (non internet connected) network.

I followed directions from the following [URL](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html) to setup Ubuntu Desktop as a router (which I assumed would allow me to use the Ubuntu VM as a internet gateway for the Windows VMs):

Let me state that I am a complete noob on Linux/Ubuntu.  I have done some very minimal work on Linux/Unix systems in the past, but it has been extremely rare and over many years.  Basically everytime I look at a Linux system, its almost as if it is my first time.

I have Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop with open-vm-tools-desktop on VMWare Player 12.
I have 2 NICs installed.  Both are set to Manual on IPv4.  One is configured with a static NAT IP that has internet connectivity, and the second is configured with a static IP on an isolated LAN Segment that contains Windows VMs.  I am not using IPv6.
The NIC names on the Ubuntu Desktop VM from ifconfig are:

```
ens33  - Internet (eth1 in example from the above URL)

ens38  - LAN (eth0 in example from the above URL - the gateway is set to the same as the IP)
```

The Ubuntu VM does have internet connectivity (verified via ping www.google.com, Firefox connectivity, and software updates).

In addition to configuring the Ubuntu NICs via the GUI, I issued the following commands (not including the comments prefaced with ----):

```
---- Enable IP forwarding commands:
sudo sh -c “echo 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip forward’’
```

I edited /etc/sysctl.conf and removed the # comment symbol from the below line and saved the file:

```
# net.ipv4.ip forward=1
```

---- IP Masquerading commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE    
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -m state -–state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT   
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT

# iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

I can ping the Ubuntu isolated LAN NIC IP from the Windows VMs, however I can't get any ping response from the internet connected NIC on the Ubuntu VM or access the internet.

I am not using DHCP in any form on Ubuntu if that matters (I do have a seperate DHCP server on the isolated LAN as well as some static IP machines).

Would someone be able to tell me what I missed in the configuration (I am hoping it might be something simple...)?

---

I found another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918789/ubuntu-as-gateway-client-pc-no-internet) from someone else that was trying to set this up here.
I notice that some of my settings are different, but I am not sure if that is the problem or if it might be related to different versions of Ubuntu??
My interfaces file does not have some of the values, but not sure if those are necessary since the NICs are configured via the GUI??
There are some differences in Routes, but I am guessing that isn't an issue....
There are some differences in the IPtables, which I'm guessing might be the issue??

---

My config info is below:

ifconfig:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.135.140  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.135.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fede:3b37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:de:3b:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3003  bytes 263817 (263.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 301  bytes 29406 (29.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens38: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.201.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.201.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fede:3b41  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:de:3b:41  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 96  bytes 9581 (9.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 246  bytes 25007 (25.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 354  bytes 26006 (26.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 354  bytes 26006 (26.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface    
0.0.0.0         192.168.135.2   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens33    
0.0.0.0         192.168.201.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens38    
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ens33
192.168.135.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens33    
192.168.201.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens38
```

IPtables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)    
target     prot opt source               destination             

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)    
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Client PC Configuration (Windows 2012R2 on LAN NIC):

```
IP:     192.168.201.5   
Subnet:     255.255.255.0    
Gatewaay:   192.168.201.1
```